# Asp.net web api controller returns 404 after a day after application launch

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to figure out a problem that occurs in my asp.net framework web.api application.
I have several projects involved in the solution, one of which is an api that works independently using IIS.
The problem is that **about a day after launch**, one of the controllers starts returning a 404 error for requests, but until then it works fine and handles all requests to it.
I tried to remove the application idle handling option in the IIS application settings, but it did not help. I also tried to arrange the code in ConfigureServices from Global.asax in this order

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure (WebApiConfig.Register);
```

and tried to add this setting to web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = "true" />
```

Application target framework is 4.5, and IIS environment version is 4.0 - as said in MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45), it corresponds to asp-net 4.5

> Note that although the .NET Framework Version column shows "v2.0" and
> "v4.0" for .NET Framework versions, these equate to ASP.NET 3.5 and
> ASP.NET 4.5

What could cause this transformation of the working controller behavior on launch and break it after working a while?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the 404 error page? Different error page can reflect whether the 404 is reported by IIS or ASP.NET. No matter which reported error, I suggest you set it display more detailed error information.

Comment: @BruceZhang Right now i can't show any responce, because we need the applicaton to run correct at the moment and i restart it manually to prevent this error. I am using Postman to execute requests, and when error occurs it shows no responce body at all, only status: 404 Not Found.

Comment: You can set <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /> and <customErrors  mode="Off"> in web.config. If you get a 404 error next time, you can see more detailed information, such as where the resource cannot be found in the URL.